# implementing an ajax loading spinner with jqtouch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtouch

I am wondering what javascript or jquery function I need to get an ajax loading spinner working with jqtouch.

I have a search button on a page which when clicked submits to a php file which processes the search results and echos back line by line the results in hthml within a 
div which jqtouch automatically puts inside a new div (this is my first jqtouch application but this seems pretty standard, new 'pages' are simply new divs in the html).

I have to have an onclick on the search button to trigger the javascript, as 'live' and similar jquery functions won't on the iphone I am testing with.
Onclick I I know to call a function to 'show' a  loading div on the page and hide it when i get a desponse but then I am lost how to detect that the php file has finished processing the page results as I don't know how jqtouch tells this.

**Edit**

```
function popup(){
    $('#popup').ajaxStart(function(){
        $(this).show();
        });

    $('#popup').ajaxComplete(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        });     

    }
```

This works on the computer but has a bug as explained in my response to bohzo below, how do I get it working on the iphone?
It's within a function as an onclick action is neccesary in my jqtouch implementation.

Comment: It's not called 'spinner'. a spinner is a number picker wit +/-

Comment: a little eye candy  http://www.ajaxload.info/

Comment: No, a spinner in this context is a small animated spinning gif which indicates the request is being processed.

Answer (score 1):

This is works for me in my app.

```
    function SubmitSearch()
    {
      $("#loading_gif").show();
      $.post('url to the php file', {var1: searchkey}, function(data) {
        $("#loading_gif").hide();

        //do something with returned data
        alert(data);
       });
    }
```

you can catch the search key in your php file as $key = $_POST[var1];
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.ajaxStart(..)`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`.ajaxComplete(..)`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

Comment: That seems to work on my computer, thanks. I will test it more and on my iPhone before I accept the answer, as I know what jqtouch is like.

Comment: Well, it works great on the computer but on the iphone it doesn't work as expected. The first time I click search the loading gif does not appear. If I click back and click search again the second time it will appear. My code is edited into my question if you would care to give your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This works for jQTouch using Zepto (haven't tested with jQuery).

CSS:

```
div#jqt #loading {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) url('../images/scanner/loading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('ajaxStart', function(){
    $('#loading').addClass('current');
});

$(document).on('ajaxStop', function(){
    $('#loading').removeClass('current');
});
```